# Exception fixing docBase: {0} tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

I am having problem with extracting war file in my local machine.In another environment
   it is extracting normally.When i use same war file in my local machine i am getting the 
   exception

**SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase: {0}
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance code**

Can any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the file in my zip file has been corrupted.That is causing this exception.